# Capybara 3 & Poltergeist normalize consecutive whitespaces

Tags: rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I've updated Capybara to version 3.29.0 (with Poltergeist 1.18.1), and the whitespaces are not normalized like in version 2, meaning the `\n` characters appear in `page.text`, which is what I expected. However, if I have consecutive newlines, like `<br><br>`, it will be collapsed to only one `\n`. Is there any way I can stop that collapsing behavior?
By the way, if I add `Capybara.default_normalize_ws = true`, all `<br>` will be normalized to standard spaces like in Capybara 2, which is not what I want.

Comment: Poltergeist is obsolete, time to move on to a modern driver which correctly implements Capybaras current API.

Comment: We will, but it takes time, and I don't know if that will fix my problem.

Comment: Easy enough to test, and at least with the selenium driver will return two blank  lines in that case